# Deus Ex Human Revolution - loading is not ending

Tags: pc, deus-ex-human-revolution

I am having a problem with Deus Ex: Human Revolution, I have been playing without any problems, but after a couple of weeks I began experiencing issues with the game getting stuck on loading screens.

After exiting or after dieing, the game is getting stuck on a loading screen. I am able to continue playing the game only after clicking 'Load Previous Auto-Save'.

I have checked on Google for other people experiencing this issue, but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your pc set to run at full performance. Mine did the same until I increased its performance in the control panel. Unlike you, though, I could not load previous saves.

How long have you waited on the loading screen? My machine usually takes 7 minutes to load.

Comment: I didn't install Update for the game. After installing the update problem was disappeared.